# Как получить данные из базы и вставить в DropdownButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как получить данные из базы данных и добавить их в список DropdownButton?

Есть код получения данных с базы (ниже, но появляется ошибка типизации), но вопрос: как их добавить в DropdownButton?
Пробовал с помощью FutureBuilder, но там при использовании атрибута value появлялась ошибка и не показывалось какой элемент выбран.

```
Future<List<DropdownMenuItem<Subject>>> _subjects() async {
    List<Subject> subjects = await DBProvider.db.getSubjects();
    return subjects.map<DropdownMenuItem<Subject>>((Subject subject){
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Subject>(
                    value: subject,
                    child: Text(subject.title),
                  );
                }).toList();
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    _subjects();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Сама ошибка:

```
The argument type 'Future<List<DropdownMenuItem<Subject>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Subject>>'.
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101779/discussion-on-question-by----------).